When the REPEATABLE READ transaction makes snapshot with SELECT FOR UPDATE in PostgreSQL?
Imagine that we have two transactions in PostgreSQL with REPEATABLE READ isolation level.
Both of them tries to make two actions:

SELECT ... FOR UPDATE
UPDATE

Imagine that both of them start approximately at same time.
So the question is - when exactly the second TX makes the snapshot?

At the beginning of TX
At the moment when the SELECT comes to DB and locks
At the moment when the DB releases the lock and completes the SELECT statement



It is spelled out here Repeatable Read: This level is different from Read Committed in that a query in a repeatable read transaction sees a snapshot as of the start of the first non-transaction-control statement in the transaction, not as of the start of the current statement within the transaction.. Read the rest of the linked docs for a more complete explanation.

Thank you for the link. So the problem is what the “as of the start of the first non-transaction-control statement“ means? What is the start? Is it the moment when statement (select in my case) came to db (the second option in the question)?

The first  SELECT FOR UPDATE  in each transaction creates the snapshot that each subsequent (non-transaction) statement in the transaction sees.  There are additional conditions for SELECT FOR UPDATE that are spelled out in the linked docs section at UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE, SELECT FOR UPDATE, and SELECT FOR SHARE commands behave the same as SELECT in terms of searching for target rows:
